# how can i verify a user after registering with email

Tags: reactjs, redux

How do I hit a verification endpoint to resend auth token like the image below in my react application
[image]

im using redux

PS: To clarify, I want to hit that `resend/token/(email address)` endpoint so it'll send the user a code to their mail then take them to a verification page where they'll put the code sent to their mail then complete their registration. I'm confused as to how I'll implement it. do I implement it in the registration component or verification component I'm using redux as state management.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is

Comment: i want to hit that endpoint so it'll send the user a code to their mail the intake them to a verification page where they'll put the code sent to their mail then complete their registration

Answer (score 0):

if i'm clearly understand  . You have to creat a route called resend , In the component resend at the life cycle didMount you get the token from the url and you send a request to api to verify the email of user   .

Comment: yes exactly that. can you help me with a sample